# Change image canvas size in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a photo in a canvas/figure and I wish to increase the canvas/figure height and width without resizing the photo (e.g, display the image in a bigger "canvas"). How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just pad the image with ones (or NaN)? See `padarray`

Comment: Hi, can you please provide my an example in combination with imread. Thanks.

Comment: It would be better if you post (a minimal subset of) your code, and then someone (I or someone else) can add the padding. For example: is your image read as an RBG image (MxNx3 array) or an indexed image (MXN array and a colormap)?

Comment: For purposes of display in a MATLAB figure or do you need to be able to write out a padded image as a common image file format? For in MATLAB display: If you change the axis units from `'Normalized'` to `'pixels'`, the axis with the image won't resize when you resize the figure. @LuisMendo Hi, Luis!

Comment: @chappjc - OMG you're back!  I <3 `accumarray`!

Comment: @rayryeng Just stopping in for a bit!  BTW, I just noticed a "nice answer" of yours.  ;)

Comment: @chappjc - Thanks :) Just got the badge :)

Comment: @chappjc Hey! Come on, don't make us beg... STAY! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borrowing from Luis Mendo's answer in the above comments, use [`padarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html).  You would call it like so, given that your image is stored in `im`:

```
out = padarray(im, [rows cols], padval, 'both');
```

`rows` and `cols` determine the pixel border you want to pad in your image, which coincides with the `both` flag.  `padval` is the value you want to place on the border when you're increasing the canvas size.  You can either do any value you want that conforms to the type of your image.  For example, you can do `0` for black, `255` for white, `128` for gray and so on.  For example, if you wanted to do a 10 pixel wide border for the rows and a 5 pixel wide border for your columns in gray, do this:

```
out = padarray(im, [10 5], 128, 'both');
```

Here's an example loading in the `onion.png` image stored in MATLAB's system path:

```
im = imread('onion.png');
out = padarray(im, [10 5], 128, 'both');
imshow(out);
```

This is what I get:

[image]

As you can see, the rows of your image are padded with a 10 pixel gray border before the start of the image (top) and after (bottom).  Similarly, the columns of your image are padded with a 5 pixel gray border before the start of the image (left) and after (right).

Simply adjust the rows and columns and graylevel intensity you want to suit your purposes.

Comment: Good answer! (Not that the OP has shown much effort, though...)

Comment: @LuisMendo - I can't resist anything related to image processing... :( lol.  There was a post I answered a few days ago where someone wanted to mimic `bwlabel` without using the built-in function.  They showed no effort, but I wrote code anyway... and it was also good practice!... thank you though :)

Comment: Yes, one does learn from those things. That's an important reward!

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks, I was trying to change your good answer to match a general case. 
For example, my image has width and height and I wish to increase the canvas to the dimension of widthMax and heightMax . Therefore, I used  w = ceil((widthMax-width)) and h = ceil((heightMax-height)) and img1 = padarray(img,[w h ],128,'both') but it did not work. Any clue why?

Comment: @user2916044 - Why does it not work?  What are your values of `widthMax`, `heightMax`, `width`, `height`?  Judging by your syntax, it should work.  My guess is that a couple of your variables aren't right.  BTW, you need to change it so that it's `[h w]` not `[w h]`.  The number of rows that you're padding need to come first, followed by the number of columns.

Comment: @rayryeng I am still lost.

If you run this code you will find that the heightNew, widthNew are not 1000, why?

img=imread('tissue.png');
[height, width, ~] = size(img)
 
heightMax=1000; 
widthMax=1000;
imgpad = padarray(img,[ceil((heightMax-height)) ceil((widthMax-width))],128,'both');
imshow(imgpad);
[heightNew, widthNew, ~] = size(imgpad)

Comment: @user2916044 you need to divide w and h by 2. W and h are what you pad TO EACH SIDE OF THE BORDER.

Answer (score 1):

If you're after MATLAB figure formatting, you can lock the image size within the figure by setting the `'units'` parameter of the axis to something other than `'normalized'` (e.g. `'pixels'`).  Combine that with the figure's `'ResizeRcn'` to get automatic repositioning of the axis with the image, and the image stays centered and the same size when you resize the figure.

**holdimg.m**

```
function holdimg(ha)
% Hold axis/image size and centering in the figure. Input ha is the axis handle.
assert(strcmpi(get(ha,'Type'),'axes'))

set(ha,'Units','pixels');
pa = get(gca,'pos'); sz = pa(3:4);
set(ancestor(ha,'figure'),'ResizeFcn',@axResizeFn);

    function axResizeFn(varargin)
        pf = get(varargin{1},'pos'); % varargin{1} is figure handle
        set(ha,'pos',[(pf(3:4)-sz)/2 sz])
    end

end
```

**Usage**

```
>> imshow(imread('cameraman.tif'))
>> % now manually resize the image (via figure size) to desired size
>> holdimg(gca) % lock image size
>> % now resize figure, image stays centered and constant size
```

[Demonstration (3MB animated GIF).](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0I-3DNmsdxFeUEwUG1BblluLUk/view)

Comment: Wow... nice animated GIF!

Comment: @rayryeng Any excuse for an animation...  and a nested function!  Too bad it's not at all what the OP was after.  Oh, well!